# Column to be populated using other columns values

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add a new column in my table using SQL code in PostgreSQL / PostGIS, the values in this column must be filled from the other eight columns and updated with a trigger as I insert data to a new line for the first rows. As I show in the attached image.

[image: Table with the new column]

I have used this code to alter the table,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN NEW_COLUMN varchar;

UPDATE table_name SET NEW_COLUMN = "PP" || '.' || "MM" || '.' || "DD" || '.' || "BB" || '.' || "QQ" || '.' || "LL" || '.' || "ID"::varchar || '.' || "UU";
```

But I am having a problem using this trigger because it does not accept:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_en() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
NEW.codigo :=; 
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 
CREATE TRIGGER update_en 
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON public."EDIFICACAO_4" 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_en();
```

Comment: Why are you storing that information to begin with? Create a view that simply returns the concatenated value.

Answer (score 2):

The question on *why* you think you need that aside, you can simplify the concatenation using `concat_ws()`which you can easily use in the trigger as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_en() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
  NEW.codigo := concat_ws('.', new."PP", new."MM", new."DD", new."BB", new."QQ", new."LL", new."ID", new."UU");
  RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hi, it worked, so the problem is, I Had more two columns i did not want to alter, so when i write this trigger, the values of this columns are no more calculated, I edited the question to see that.

Comment: @RosárioDilo: then include the calculation of those columns in that trigger.

Comment: @Janel27, iam having difficult to rearrange that, in that trigger where do i include the calculation of those columns and where do i include also their trigger? Remember that those two columns can note appear to add the code.

Comment: @RosárioDilo: please add a new question for that including your complete trigger code and your attempts to update the other columns as well.

Comment: Hi, @Janel27, i have created another answer in the following link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220329/populate-a-column-using-the-values-of-other-ones?noredirect=1#comment432346_220329